# Manage Protractor tests with a single Gulp task

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to get e2e testing going with on my angular project using Gulp.

I'm able to get it working, but only if I manually launch a standalone selenium server using `webdriver-manager start` in a seperate terminal window.

Ideally I would like my gulp task to manage starting and stopping the server so as to not add more overhead for my team to run these tests.

I got set up following the instructions here:

> https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor

They describe 2 options for starting the selenium server. One is to set up a gulp task which appears to do the same thing as `webdriver-manager start`:

```
gulp.task('webdriver_standalone', require("gulp-protractor").webdriver_standalone);
```

This *works*, but not when I have my e2eTest task invoke it as a dependency. I have to run `gulp webdriver_standalone` in a seperate terminal window.

I cannot understand the other suggested option.

> point to the selenium jar in the protractor config file

These instructions require a path to the *selenium-server-standalone jar*, in `protractor`s `node_modules` (`./node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar`), but my `node_modules/protractor/` directory does not have such a jar (or a `selenium` sub-directory at all)

The instructions for [Running Protractor without a plugin](https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor#user-content-running-protractor-without-a-plugin) seem to have the same problem of having to run the selenium server in another terminal window.

Is there a way to get this set up so that a single gulp task starts the standalone server, runs the tests, and shuts it down with no other intervention?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run Protractor you have several options regarding Selenium WebDriver (remember that WebDriver is web-service written in Java):

1. Run with Protractor with remote (standalone) service. It can be either local or on different machine. If Selenium is on different machine then your web app should be publicly available, not just localhost. If you choose to use standalone Selenium service then you configure your config file/Gulp task with seleniumAddress option.
2. "Ask" Protractor to run Selenium for you. In this case Protractor will run Selenium WebDriver with the Jar file you provide in seleniumServerJar configuration.
3. Do not use Selenium WD. Use direct connect instead, which is compatible with Chrome and (probably) Firefox only.

In your case simply run:

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

It will download Selenium. Then point config to the right jar.

Comment: I think my problem is that I was not able to locate the `.jar` file. Not at all sure what changed since asking this question, but I figured it out by running `ps -ef` while the server was running. Low and behold, it was exactly where my original question said I couldn't find it: `./node_modules/protractor/selenium/`

Comment: Also thanks for mentioning `direct connect`, I hadn't heard of that.

Comment: I plan on using a remote Selenium server in our CI pipeline, but for local development I want to get Protractor to do it for me. Do you agree that this sounds like the best option>

Comment: I'm also looking at doing the same thing but haven't found a good solution yet!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get this working locally is using a local Selenium Standalone jar, as Igor suggested in option #2. (It is pretty difficult to get gulp to run `webdriver-manager start` as a spawned child_process or async task.) 
You can get that jar in your `node_modules` folder easily by using:

`npm install selenium-server-standalone-jar --save-dev`

Then, in your `protractor.conf.js` comment out or remove the *seleniumAddress* line and add a line for *seleniumServerJar*.

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    /* Lines below for completeness only, leave yours as is. */
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    specs: ['login-spec.js'],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }]
};
```

Comment: By default, Protractor now looks to `node_modules/protractor/selenium/...` for a Selenium server. If Protractor is locally installed via `npm`, Selenium is already there, so there's no need to do a separate install of `selenium-server-standalone-jar`. According to [the docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L30), `seleniumServerJar:` will default to `node_modules/protractor/selenium/...` unless another method of starting Selenium is configured. This means that there is no need to update `seleniumServerJar:` every time the Selenium server is updated.